# python select range from list of list

Tags: python, list

Is there a pythonic (please no numpy!) way to select a subset list-of-lists from a list-of-lists? In MATLAB, the behavior I'm trying to mimic can be exemplified with something like `A(2:7, 5:8)`.

This isn't a homework problem, just looking for a clean solution.

Here's a concrete example:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
select(A, (1, 3), (0, 3))
```

should yield

```
[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: Can you please provide input lists and expected output?

Comment: you could use recursive slicing like : `myList[1][3]`

Comment: **Why** should the arguments lead to the expected output

Comment: like the `range` function, the first number is included, the second excluded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass arguments to slices:

```
def select(lst, subselect, select):
    return [sublst[slice(*subselect)] for sublst in lst[slice(*select)]]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def select(lst, subselect, select):
...     return [sublst[slice(*subselect)] for sublst in lst[slice(*select)]]
... 
>>> A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> select(A, (1, 3), (0, 3))
[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

You can even use `None` to indicate default values for slicing (so `0` for `start` and the length of the input list for the `stop` argument) or pass in just *one* argument to specify a `stop` argument:

```
>>> select(A, (1, None), (3,))
[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

and a third argument gives you the option to specify a stride. If the stride is negative, the list is reversed:

```
>>> select(A, (1, None), (None, 3, 2))
[[2, 3], [8, 9]]
>>> select(A, (1, None), (None, None, -1))
[[8, 9], [5, 6], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`select(A, (1, 3), (0, 3))` can be implemented as `[x[1:3] for x in A[0:3]]`

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]
>>> [x[1:3] for x in A[0:3]]
[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
>>>
```